# ASP.NET Core MVC using query string parameter to automatically populate a form field with the same name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I noticed that ASP.NET Core MVC will take a query string parameter and use its value to automatically populate a form field with the same name, even if I ignore the query string parameter and explicitly set the model property to `null`.

I have a [reproduction on GitHub](https://github.com/jonsagara/AspNetCoreMvcQueryStringToForm).

### The Model (`Models/HomeIndexModel.cs`)

This is a simple `record` with one property, `Email`. This is bound to the lone textbox on the form.

```cs
public record HomeIndexModel(string? Email);
```

### The Controller Action (`Controllers/HomeController.cs`)

The controller action takes a `string?` from the query string and binds it to the `email` parameter.

Note how we're ignoring this value and explicitly setting the view model's `Email` property to `null`.

```cs
public IActionResult Index(string? email)
{
    // NOTE: Ignore the query string parameter and explicitly set the view model property to null.
    return View(new HomeIndexModel(Email: null));
}
```

### The View (`Views/Home/Index.cshtml`)

The view uses `HomeIndexModel` as its view model. It has a single form with a textbox for `HomeIndexModel`'s `Email` property.

```
@model AspNetCoreMvcQueryStringToForm.Models.HomeIndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    
    <form>
        <label asp-for="Email"> Email
            <input type="email" asp-for="Email" />
        </label>
        
    </form>
</div>
```

### The Unexpected behavior

If I make a request to the action with an email query string parameter, the `Email` form field is automatically populated with that value, even though I'm explicitly setting the `Email` model property to null in the controller action:

[image]

### Question

How and why is this happening? I must be overlooking something simple.

Is there a way to disable this behavior, preferably at the action level?

Comment: You are positive that `Index(string? email)` is actually being called? There isn't another overload of `Index(...)` that may be triggered instead?

Comment: You need to place some breakpoints... maybe rebuild the app before debugging it. Pretty sure you are mistaken

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's the only action in the controller, and the project, for that matter.

Comment: And, yes, I rebuilt many times, and hit breakpoints in various places, including in the view.

Comment: `asp-for` will populate form fields from `ModelState`. Mostly this is so that invalid values will be preserved. eg you can't bind `"abc"` to an `int`, but you want to re-render the form with the invalid value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to disable this behavior, preferably at the action
> level?

Two tricks for you:

1. In your action add the code:

   ```
   ModelState.Clear()/ModelState.Remove("email")
   ```
2. Modify the name of the argument in your controller:

   ```
   public IActionResult Index(string? mail)
   ```

Comment: Removing `email` from `ModelState` did the trick. I set a breakpoint and confirmed that `email` is in ModelState, and marked as Valid. 

Thank you, and thank you, too, Jeremy Lakeman, for the insights.